# How create a np.sin() with interval of date and time?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How create a `np.sin()` with interval of date and time ?

`np.arange(0, 100, 0.1)`: Not return error for creation array

```
start = pd.Timestamp('2015-07-01')
end = pd.Timestamp('2015-08-01')
t = np.linspace(start.value, end.value, 100)
time = pd.to_datetime(t)

#time = np.arange(0, 100, 0.1)
sin = np.sin(time) + np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=len(time))
```

**Error:**

```
    sin = np.sin(time) + np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=len(time))
TypeError: ufunc 'sin' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

**Print time:**

> np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)]) DatetimeIndex([
>   '2015-07-01 00:00:00',
>                  '2015-07-01 07:30:54.545454592',
>                  '2015-07-01 15:01:49.090909184',
>                  '2015-07-01 22:32:43.636363520',
>                  '2015-07-02 06:03:38.181818112', ....

Comment: Why we need sin with datetime object ?, what is your expected output ?

Comment: it doesn't have to be datetime, just the values ​​are time series

Comment: `np.sin` is a function of angle, measred in `radians`.  It has nothing to do with time or date,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are creating a timeseries based on the time, the time has to mean something so you can convert it a radians and then apply sin function I would suggest an approach based on the time difference in seconds:

```
start = pd.Timestamp('2015-07-01')
end = pd.Timestamp('2015-08-01')
t = np.linspace(start.value, end.value, 100)
time = pd.to_datetime(t)

np.random.seed(0)
t = np.sin(np.radians((time - time.min()).seconds)) + \
    np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=len(time))
```

A plot would be:

[image]